# Office plant identification

Tags: identification, office-gardening

Does anybody know what plant is this?

[image: tropical shrub in my office]

Comment: If you [add the image to your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/299974), you ensure other readers will benefit from it even when the cloud-hosted image is gone.

Comment: I use the website from my smartphone and I don't have a very easy way to do that. The app might have what I need, but I don't want to install it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This tree looks like a Ficus Benjamina or close relative. These are also common office and house plants because they are fairly easy to care for. They tolerate low light levels fairly well, though they may not support as many leaves when the light is so low.

In humid conditions they sometimes grow air roots out of their branches. If the roots touch the ground, they develop into secondary truncks.

You just have to keep them watered properly. Which is to say, loose well draining soil but watered often enough that the soil never gets dry.

Comment: It might be some sort of ficus. Bit probably not benjamina. My plant's leaves are thicker, I would say.

Comment: That's why I said or some relative. Benjamina is the closest I could get based on the picture.

Comment: It's not a Benjamina or the leaves would come to a sharp point. More likely to be Ficus Nitida.  Definitely a ficus now Sorin has Id'ed white sap

Answer (score 2):

This is a ficus retusa. They're often used as bonsai.